# Problem while creating reminder for recurring events in Google Calendar like "twice a day", "Thrice a day"

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am trying to set recurring reminders for a particular event as in the image. Code works correctly but there is something happening which is changing create events. Please check details as below.

If I try setting reminders from loop, it works, but with recurrence there is an issue as mentioned.

[image: It's correct time which is selected]

Check for first two reminders shown on the image were timed perfectly when they were set using this code snippet.

but after like 30 secs it all changed back to the same time. 
[image: Check Time For Events now]

I have to set reminders for different events like twice a day, thrice a day and all

> **Please check code snippet as below (For an Event occurring Twice a Day):**

```
       Uri uri;
       Uri EVENTS_URI = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase().toString());
       Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
       current.setTimeInMillis(((TimeStamp.formatToSeconds(mBinder.etStartDate.getText().toString().trim(), DATE_FORMAT_FOR_SHIFT) + time) * 1000L));
       ContentResolver cr = mActivity.getContentResolver();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
       values.put("calendar_id", calId);
       values.put("title", getString(R.string.app_name) + " - " + mBinder.etSearch.getText().toString().trim());
       values.put("description", getString(R.string.app_name) + " - " + mBinder.etSearch.getText().toString().trim());
       values.put("eventLocation", "Medication Area");
       long startTime = ((TimeStamp.formatToSeconds(mBinder.etStartDate.getText().toString().trim(), DATE_FORMAT_FOR_SHIFT) + time) * 1000L);
       values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTime);
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
       long endtime = (TimeStamp.formatToSeconds(mBinder.etEndDate.getText().toString().trim(), DATE_FORMAT_FOR_SHIFT) + time);
       endDate.setTimeInMillis(((TimeStamp.formatToSeconds(mBinder.etEndDate.getText().toString().trim(), DATE_FORMAT_FOR_SHIFT) + time) * 1000L));
       values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+PT30M");
       values.put("allDay", 0);
       values.put("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=18,6;UNTIL=20181129");
       values.put("eventTimezone", timeZone.getID());
       values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
       values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_COLOR, ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.app_purple));
       uri = cr.insert(EVENTS_URI, values);
       Log.e("Uri:::", uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that the cause of a problem is due to a bug in the service itself, you can [search the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:191627+%20type:bug) to determine if it is a known issue. If the issue is completely new, you can [report it on the Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191627&template=824103) as well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will do that and let's see if someone can help me with this